# Count words in Document when user begins typing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to create an addon for Google Docs. I want to get the count of words in a document dynamically when the user starts typing.

Comment: You're asking for a specific trigger, so have you even read which triggers are available in Apps Script for Google Docs? (Hint: you're going to need an elaborate approach to achieve your desired frequency of operation, because you do not have native Google Apps Script methods available to you.)

Comment: @tehhowch is right, there's no "onType" event in GAS. Would a time interval satisfy your needs? "Check word count every X seconds?"

Comment: @MeirGabay note that the minimum value of "X seconds" for an add-on is 3600

Comment: Currently, I've done it using a recursive call on '.getText()'.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose `documentContent` is the variable in which the string is being saved, You do something like this.

```
let documentString = 'a lot of content that the user typed ..';
let wordCount = documentString.split(' ').length;
console.log(wordCount); // This is going to print => 9
```

Comment: but, I want to check the length dynamically on the user typing.
something like onchange event.

Comment: You might want to remove double and trailing spaces and maybe only allow A-Za-z0-9 with single spaces

Comment: @adeel note that `let` is not a valid keyword in Google Apps Script